# Can you give helpers a variable and change the function it uses in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am creating a form and I want to make a custom error log, for example when the user leaves e-mail empty, I want to give my error_helper the variable email, sending to the user that he did not fill in this variable and log that he left this empty. I am a starter with codeIgniter and i've read the manual but I did not find anything helpful. Here is my code:

```
    public function submitCheck() {
    $this->load->model("User");
    if(empty($post['email'] || 'email'==""))
    {
        echo "Email is empty."; //This will be changed to a view for user    
        $this->load->helper('error'); //Loading the helper
        errorLog('Firstname'); //Variable I want to give to the errorLog function.
        exit();
    }
```

So here I've given my errorLog a variable, wich I want to use in my error_helper

```
    function errorLog(){         
     if(errorLog() == 'email') //Here I want to change the error function based on what variable I give to errorLog
     {
        log_message('error', 'Email was empty');
        exit();
     }
}
```

Is this possible to do or some other way how I can change the function based on what variable I give my errorLog. 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass `parameter` into your helper function

**Controller file**

```
public function submitCheck() {
    $this->load->model("User");
    if(empty($post['email']))
    {
       // echo "Email is empty."; //This will be changed to a view for user    
        $this->load->helper('error'); //Loading the helper
     echo  $msg= errorLog('Firstname'); //Variable I want to give to the errorLog function.
    }
```

**Helper file**

```
    function errorLog($var){ // get the variable thet you have pass from your helper        
         if($var == 'email') //Here I want to change the error function based on what variable I give to errorLog
         {
            return log_message('error', 'Email was empty');// here you use return type

         }
         if($var == 'test') 
         {
            return log_message('error', 'Test was empty');// here you use return type

         }
}
```

Also load your helper in `controller constructor` file or `autoload.php` file

Comment: This worked for me, thanks a lot! Do you mean I need to create a controller constructor or make one in my own controller? (Sorry for the noob question)

Answer (score 1):

Read parameter in the function:

```
    function errorLog($var){         
     if($var== 'email') //Here I want to change the error function based on what variable I give to errorLog
     {
        log_message('error', 'Email was empty');
        exit();
     }
}
```